# How to break this sentence to smaller sentences

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

Consider:

> OMINI data extraction method builds on the hypothesis (assumes) **that there** is a unique data region, which is the largest region in the web document, **that this region contains** multiple data records, **that some tags are more** likely to be data record separators based on their type and their occurrences, and **that counting on an** ontology helps identify data records.

It includes several assumptions that all refer back to "It assumes that ...". I want to break these sentences to separated sentences. Something like:

> It assumes that there is a unique data region, which is the largest region in the web document, **that** contains multiple data records separated by certain tags. It also assumes that counting on an ontology helps identify data records.

First, I am not sure about using the second **that**. Moreover, it is still long. If I want to shorten it further I may lose the connections between them or be forced to repeat "It assumes". I need some guide to overcome this issues.

Comment: What do you mean by **unique**? And remember, best not to start your text here with something that needs prior context to be understood, (e.g. "It").

Comment: And what do you meaning by "counting on an ontology"?

Comment: @TRomano, see [Ontology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontology_(information_science)).  It seems an overly formal way to say that each record has unique indices -- but might be perfectly normal in academia.

Comment: @Andrew: my question is about the entire phrase.  How can "counting on" something "help to identify"?

Comment: @TRomano Actually its not my sentences, I try to paraphrase it. its maybe "relying on"...

Answer (score 5):

You're looking at a virtual list.  You're not going to be able to break it down into separate sentences without rewriting, but you can turn it into a formal list, e.g.:

It builds on the hypothesis (assumes) that:

- there is a unique data region, which is the largest region in the web
  document,
- this region contains multiple data records,
- some tags are more likely to be data record separators based on their
  type and their occurrences, and
- counting on an ontology helps
  identify data records.

---

To present it as a paragraph instead of a bulleted list, Ahmad, you'll either have to accept the original form, which is *very* long, or re-write. Just adding punctuation won't help enough.

If I needed to re-write, the result might be something like this:

*It assumes that there is a unique data region, and that that region is the largest region in the web document.  Such a region contains data records that are delimited by certain tags that act as separators.  These separators can be identified ontologically because of their nature and their frequency.*

That separates the original into 3 concepts:  there is a single data region; it has records that have separators; the separators, and thus the records, can be identified by looking for a certain kind of repetitiveness.

On the other hand, since I don't have any context, I'm just guessing at the meaning, and might have turned what you wrote into nonsense.  If I did, I apologise and hope you can at least get a sense of direction from it.

Comment: Good! but how can I write them in a paragraph without using bullets (I mean the punctuation that is required)

Comment: @Ahmad: Items in a (non-bulleted) list are conventionally separated by semi-colons.